# HTTPS with Nginx and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

So I used certbot to configure Nginx for https. That worked well (I used the automatic configuration).

Now how can I configure my Node.js back end to be able to make GET/POST requests from the front end that is being hosted with Nginx?

EDIT:

```
location /api {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #server port
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have correctly configured your Nginx with SSl and your node application. The requests you send should work with https://URL . Please check your nginx.conf and verify the following things.

You can add ssl cert in Nginx with

```
ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt #cert location
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key #key location
```

in your server block in Nginx.And your nodejs App should be configured like this in the server block

```
 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #server port
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
```

This will be sufficient for your server to work with SSL.

Comment: but then i can not access the files in /var/www/html

Comment: Add a separate location block in server for that like.

 location /public {
    root /var/www/html;
  }

Comment: i did it like in my original post and it worked perfectly thanks alot!